# binding data received in subscribe call to viewmodel knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

On a textbox change subscribe call, I'm getting relevant data from the server.
I would like to understand how to bind this data to my viewmodel such that it is available to my html code..

My html code:

```
    <div><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: gname" /></div>

    <div>
        <table>

            <tbody>
                <tr data-bind="with:gdetails">
                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: $root.eventschemas, optionsText: 'schema', value:eventschemacondition().schema"></select>

                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code:

```
var AppScope = function () {
            function EventSchemaCondition(data) {
                this.schema = ko.observable(data.schema);

            }

            function Gdetails(data) {
                this.eventschemacondition = ko.observable(data.eventschemacondition);
            }

            function G(data) {
                this.gname = ko.observable(data.gname);
                this.gdetails = ko.observable(data.gdetails);
                this.gname.subscribe(function (val) {
                    console.log(val + "subscribe fired");
                    //go to server and get data
                    var events = [{ "schema": "Test" }, { "schema": "Another Test" }];

                });
            }

            function GsViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.g = ko.observable(
                new G({
                    gname: "",
                    gdetails: new Gdetails({ eventschemacondition: new EventSchemaCondition({ schema: "" }) })
                }));

                self.eventschemas = ko.observableArray();
            }

            ko.applyBindings(new GsViewModel());
        }();
```

What I want to do is attach the data available in 'events' variable in my 'gname' subscribe call to 'eventschemas' object in GSViewModel.

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to recommend the best course of action on an abstract example. For example, without knowing what your 'G' data model really looks like, I don't know whether the "go to server and get data" function really has to be on 'G', or whether it could be safely moved into the view model.

Assuming that 'G' is the right object, I would split it up according to this logic:

1) the act of *loading* data from the server remains responsibility of your data model 'G'. But instead of subscribing to its name field and doing that automatically, we make it a callable function called `getEventsForName`

2) the act of *searching* is an ability of the user interface, and thus the responsibility of the view model. So we give your view model an `eventSearchField` observable for the search `<input>`, and have it call `G` under the hood to get the new events and populate `eventschemas` with it

```
var AppScope = function () {
    function EventSchemaCondition(data) {
        this.schema = ko.observable(data.schema);
    }

    function Gdetails(data) {
        this.eventschemacondition = ko.observable(data.eventschemacondition);
    }

    function G(data) {
        this.gname = ko.observable(data.gname);
        this.gdetails = ko.observable(data.gdetails);

        this.getEventsForName = function getEventsForName(name) {
            //go to server and get data
            return events = [{
                "schema": "Test"
            }, {
                "schema": "Another Test"
            }];
        };
    }

    function GsViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.g = ko.observable(
            new G({
                gname: "",
                gdetails: new Gdetails({
                    eventschemacondition: new EventSchemaCondition({
                        schema: ""
                    })
                })
            })
        );

        self.eventschemas = ko.observableArray();

        self.eventSearchField = ko.observable();
        self.eventSearchField.subscribe(function(searchTerm) {
          var searchResults = self.g().getEventsForName(searchTerm);

          self.g().gname(searchTerm);
          self.eventschemas(searchResults);
        });
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new GsViewModel());
}();
```

I don't know your exact binding scope from the markup snippet you posted, but I am going to guess that `$data` is `self.g()`, and `$parent` is your view model:

```
<div><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $parent.eventSearchField" /></div>

<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-bind="with:gdetails">
                <td>
                    <select data-bind="options: $root.eventschemas, optionsText: 'schema', value:eventschemacondition().schema"></select>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any specific utility of creating a separate method geteventsforname and then calling it in subscribe call  rather than going the server and geting data in subscribe call itself..

Comment: As I said - I don't know, that depends on your design of the real class 'G'. If you see no specific need to, then loading the data directly in the view model is absolutely fine as well.